# Hibernates loads the entire hierarchy even though some fields are lazy

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

While using the get to lazy load an attribute or use fetch join in JPQL I get more the entire hierarchy of lazy loaded Class even though some of its fields are lazy as well.

The application uses:
- spring boot
- spring data jpa 2.1.6
- hibernate-core 5.3.9
- we have open in view false
- lombok 2.1

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class BT{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<PT> pt;
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ST> s;

@Entity
@Audited
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class ST{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long id;
    private Integer checkIntervalOffline;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private B b;
}


@Entity
@Audited
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC  )
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class B{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<P> p;
}


@Entity
@Audited
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class P{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<F> features;
}


@Entity
@Audited
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class F{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long id;
    private String value;
}
```

Using fetch join

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT b FROM BT b JOIN FETCH b.s")
    List<BundleTemplate> findAllWithSubscription();
```

using get

```
public static BTDto btEntity2DtoWithS(BT entity) {
 entity.getSubscriptions();
```

I expected to get just the subscription related queries:
1. For Fetch Join:

```
select bt.id as id1_13_0_, s.id as id1_57_1_, si2_.b_id as b_11_57_1_, 
from bt bt0_ 
inner join bt_st si1_ on bt0_.id=si1_.bt_id 
inner join st si2_ on si1_.s_id=si2_.id
```

2. For Get to get something similar.

Bun actually i get a lot of additional queries for all other entities:

````
select b_.id as id1_2_0_ from b b0_ where b0_.id=?
select p0_.b_id as b_i1_6_0_, p0_.p_id as p2_6_0_, p1_.id as id1_35_1_product1_.pt_id as p_5_35_1_
from bp p0_ 
inner join p p1_ on p0_.p_id=p1_.id 
where p0_.b_id=?
and also for f
```

So somehow spring jpa tries to get the entire dependency tree for me ignoring the lazy.
````

Comment: No, I bet it doesn't. Your code, or your JSON serializer, or your XML serializer, uses the entities and navigates through the associations, and that's what triggers the (lazy) loading of the associations. Side note: you made your code incorrect and completely unreadable by renaming your classes to single or double letter class names. Please don't do that.

Comment: Execute the query and do absolutely nothing with the result, and I bet you won't see the additional queries.

Comment: Changed to do nothing :
`public List<BTDto> getAllBTWithS() {
        BTRepository.findAllWithS();
        return List.of();
    }`

` @Query(value = "SELECT b FROM BT b LEFT JOIN FETCH b.s")
    List<BT> findAllWithS();`
But the additional queries are still there

Comment: Do you use your debugger to do this experiment? If so, don't.

Comment: No, I'm not in debug mode.

Comment: Then sorry, I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, I figured out the problem. It was Lombok, it generates the hashcode with all fields by default and it was forcing the lazy loading.

Comment: Hah. Good catch. Congrats.